# What is the difference between calling the thread.start() method in an constructor and a method

Tags: java, multithreading, constructor

Eg. - take the class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class flashThread implements Runnable {
private JLabel temp;
Thread thread;
Color randColor;

public flashThread(JLabel toFlash) {
    temp = toFlash;
    thread = new Thread(this);
}

public void run() {
    Random r = new Random();
    while (true) {
        temp.setForeground(new Color(r.nextInt(246) + 10,
                r.nextInt(246) + 10, r.nextInt(246) + 10));
        String tempString = temp.getText();
        temp.setText("");
        try {
            thread.sleep(r.nextInt(500));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        temp.setText(tempString);
        try {
            thread.sleep(r.nextInt(500));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}

public void begin() {
    thread.start();
}

}
```

If I added thread.start() in the constructor, when I create two objects of the flashThread, Only one of them flashes. However, If i remove then, add the begin() method and then call the begin method from the class that initialized both flashThread objects, they both flash.

Any Help - I've only just started to learn about threads.

Thanks in advance!
-Me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please start your class name with a capital letter since this is convention in java.
It doesn't matter if you start your thread in the constructor or in a method. One problem is that you access UI elements outside of the [Event Dispatching Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (EDT), which is the only one which is allowed to access, UI elements.
Use [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29) instead. Furthermore invoke static methods like [Thread#sleep](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) on classes e.g. `Thread.sleep(1000);` not on instances.
So updating your code would look like:

```
public class FlashThread implements Runnable {
  private JLabel temp;
  Thread thread;
  Color randColor;

  public FlashThread(JLabel toFlash) {
    temp = toFlash;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
  }

  public void run() {
    final Random r = new Random();
    while (true) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){
           public void run() {
              // this will be executed in the EDT
              temp.setForeground(new Color(r.nextInt(246) + 10,
                r.nextInt(246) + 10, r.nextInt(246) + 10));
              // don't perform long running tasks in the EDT or sleep
              // this would lead to non-responding user interfaces
           }
        });
        // Let our create thread sleep
        try {
            Thread.sleep(r.nextInt(500));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I must add, though, the starting a thread in a constructor is never a good idea. If there were derived classes of this class, the thread would be started before the whole class initialization had been completed, and thread may possibly interact with a partially initialized object.

Comment: It is not safe to start the Thread even without a derived class.  The JLabel temp might be uninitialized when the run method is called.

Answer (score 0):

if you call new Thread(this) in your constructor, you are passing a reference to your object before it is fully created - hence it should not work properly at all times.